# Constructor BusRoute in class BusRoute cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

The Scottish champions lost 4-1 to Legia Warsaw as Red Bull Salzburg and Zenit were stunned and Lille secured a priceless win against Grasshoppers

Ten-man Celtic lost 4-1 at Legia Warsaw in the Champions League third qualifying round first leg, with the hosts missing two penalties.

The Scottish champions, who won this tournament under its former guise of the European Cup in 1967, got off to a superb start when Callum McGregor put them ahead in the eighth minute.

But that was as good as it got for Ronny Deila's men as their gameplan quickly collapsed.

Winger Miroslav Radovic equalised two minutes later and then added a second in the 36th minute, before Celtic saw Efe Ambrose shown a straight red card a minute before the break.

Ivica Vrdoljak subsequently sent a penalty wide for the hosts just before the hour mark, but Celtic were unable to heed the warning as Michal Zyro did make it three in the 84th minute.

Vrdoljak then saw a second spot-kick saved by Fraser Forster three minutes from the end, only for Jakub Kosecki to add a fourth in stoppage time.

There were mixed fortunes for the other former winners involved at this stage, as 1986 champions Steaua Bucharest claimed a useful 2-2 draw against Aktobe, although they led twice in Kazakhstan.

Feyenoord, meanwhile - champions in 1970 - went down 2-1 at home to Beskitas and now have it all to do in a tricky second leg in Turkey.

Red Bull Salzburg suffered a shock 2-1 defeat in a feisty clash with Qarabag which saw three men sent off.

Danilo Dias put the Azerbaijanis ahead in the second minute, and Salzburg's task was made even harder by defender Christian Schwegler's dismissal 32 minutes later.

The numbers were evened up three minutes before the break, Admir Teli shown his second caution, and Salzburg levelled the scores with 13 minutes to go courtesy of Jonatan Soriano.

Qaraba's Reynaldo was at the centre of the action towards the end, scoring the winner in the 86th minute but then getting himself sent off two minutes later as the hosts held on to take an advantage back to Austria.

Sebastien Corchia and Ryan Mendes earned Lille a 2-0 win at Grasshoppers to put them in the driving seat ahead of the second leg of their tie, while Lukas Gikiewicz's strike means AEL of Cyprus will take a narrow 1-0 lead into their decider against Andre Villas-Boas' Zenit in Russia.

Marcelo Brozovic earned Dinamo Zagreb a 1-0 win away at Aalborg, while a goal deep into stoppage time from Damjan Bohar gave Maribor victory by the same scoreline at home to Maccabi Tel Aviv.

APOEL hold the upper hand over HJK after coming back to draw 2-2 courtesy of two away goals in Finland, while Dnipro were held 0-0 at home by Copenhagen.

Elsewhere, the games between Standard Liege and Panathinaikos and Ludogorets and Partizan Belgrade also finished goalless.

Comment: public BusRoute() . like that? do i need to add ; or {} afterwards?

Comment: Perhaps you should read your Java tutorial again...

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor requires a string as an argument (which you have called `name`):

```
public BusRoute(String name) {
    // ...
}
```

If you want to use the argumentless-contrstructor, you need to declare it as so:

```
public BusRoute() {
    this.name = "Unknown";
}
```

This is because, as other answers have pointed out, when you declare your own constructor, the Java compiler no longer automatically creates an argument-less one for you.

---

EDIT: This would also work as a simplified version:

```
public BusRoute(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.bounds = new BoundingBox();
    segments = new ArrayList<Segment>();
    //this.mapURL = mapURL;
}

public BusRoute() {
    this("Unknown");
}
```

This way, you also get those bounds and segments being set up properly.

Comment: public BusRoute(String name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.bounds = new BoundingBox();
  segments = new ArrayList<Segment>();
 }
    
    public BusRoute() {
     this.name = "Unknown";
    }

Comment: Hi @ildiavolo - yes, this should work for you now. You might want to simplify it a little - I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hello, but BusRoute is not defined in BusRoute("Unknown");

Comment: "The BusRoute(String) is undefined for the type BusRoute

Answer (score 0):

When you define a constructor with parameters in a class, the compiler no more automatically defines a parameterless constructor (what is does when you don't). So just define explicitly a constructor additionally like `BusRoute()`, and you can call it again.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no constructor then compiler will provide a no-arg constructor by default. But once you provide a parameterized constructor, compiler will not provide the no-arg constructor anymore. Since while creating the object you are calling a no-arg constructor but it does not exist, so you are getting the error. In order to avoid that either pass the parameter while calling or create a no-arg constructor.